# Windows Mobil Apps Store Define Install and Uninstall

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-mobile

Is there anyone can suggest how windows mobile store define install and uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Dashboard can only allow you to see how many people have installed your app. But you could also review more demographic and platform details by Apply filters, which is on the top right corner of Acquisitions page. You could change the option as below to filter the data you’re concerned about. More details you could refer to [Acquisitions report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/acquisitions-report).

Also if you really need to know the data about app install and uninstall, please submit feedback with this feature request to [feedback hub app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n).